# Prisma client select all rows from a table

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, orm, prisma

how can I select everything from a table with prisma? (SELECT * FROM application)

```
const applications = prisma.application.findMany({
        // Returns all user fields
        include: {
            posts: {
                select: {
                    age: true,
                    about_section: true,
                    user_id: true
                },
            },
        },
    })
    console.log(applications.age)
```

Here is how my schema looks:

```
model application {
  application_id Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  age            String? @db.VarChar(255)
  about_section  String? @db.VarChar(255)
  user_id        Int?
  users          users?  @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [user_id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict, map: "application_ibfk_1")

  @@index([user_id], map: "user_id")
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For rows, `findMany()` without `where` will return all rows in table:

[Get all Records](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#get-all-records)
The following findMany query returns all User records:

```js
const users = await prisma.user.findMany()
```

---

For columns/fields, without specifying `include` or `select`, prisma has a [default](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/select-fields#return-the-default-selection-set):

> By default, when a query returns records (as opposed to a count), the
> result includes the default selection set:
>
> - All scalar fields defined in the Prisma schema (including enums)
> - None of the relations

For `SELECT * FROM application` (does not include `users` relation):

```
const applications = await prisma.application.findMany();
```

To futher include `users` relation in the model:

```
const applications = await prisma.application.findMany({
  include: {
    users: true // will include all fields
  }
});
```